# Thread em estado WAIT

Tags: java, thread, tomcat

Estou monitorando um sistema que foi feito em Java e em determinados momentos ao decorrer do dia a grande maioria das Threads, cerca de 95%, entram em estado WAIT e ficam aguardando por cerca de 50 segundos em média, e as vezes o intervalo entre as pausas é de 5 minutos. O Resultado é que todas as requisições dos usuários ficam esperando.

A minha dúvida é como saber qual Thread colocou todas as outras para esperar? 
Já usei alguns softwares que analisam Thread Dump, mas não consegui localizar a causa ainda.

Estou desconfiando que seja o GC que ao limpar a memória colocou tudo em pausa até terminar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem, próximo as 10:16 a grande maioria entrou no estado WAIT, tive que cortar a foto pois tem muito mais Threads  e todas no mesmo estado.

Comment: A sua pergunta não está suficientemente clara. As suas threads fazem a mesma coisa (isto é, implementam a mesma função, apenas com execução paralela)? O que exatamente elas fazem? Há alguma interação entre as threads que possa estar fazendo com que fiquem em espera (*idle*)? Sem esses detalhes, dificilmente alguém vai conseguir te ajudar.